# Get value from url codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a domain and id is coming in that domain like this
http://www.test.com/update_record_row/id/6356/

I want id value from the domain without passing ? instead of / in (query string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="http://www.test.com/update_record_row/6356/"> ID </a>

public function update_record_row($id)
{
    echo "Id is :".$id;
}
```

or

Use [URI segment](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html#uri-class)

```
// if URL -http://www.test.com/update_record_row/id/6356/
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);

// if URL -http://www.test.com/update_record_row/6356/
$id = $this->uri->segment(2);
```

Comment: Fixed minor issue. :)

Answer (score 6):

Using `$this->uri->segment()` you get the URL parameter

```
$this->uri->segment(1)
```

For more ..https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html

Answer (score 0):

Use  $this->uri->segment() to retreive passed value through url

If URL is `http://www.test.com/update_record_row/id/6356/`
You should use `$this->uri->segment(3);`

---

Codeigniter has awesome userguide.Just check this in in uri part.
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html#uri-class